# how we can set sequential execution of azure service bus queue..?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have three queue in my project.
1.verify email and number.
2.register user.
3.perform investment operation like. deposit, withdrawn, invest etc.

I want the flow of execution is first then second when second is running first run next record. and when second is completed then third.. because we have some data dependency for all.

how I create this kind of sequence of queue
queue 1

```
Trace.TraceInformation("verification is started");
        BrokeredMessage verificationqueuedata = Client.Receive();
        try
        {
            if (creditcheckqueuedata != null)
            {
                UserModel userModel = verificationqueuedata.GetBody<UserModel>();
                if (userModel == null)
                {
                    verificationqueuedata.Abandon();
                }
                else
                {//project code
verificationqueuedata.Complete();
}
}
```

all the three queue are created in same manner..
Support me for creating of sequence

Comment: sounds mroe like you need a workflow engine, not just queues. Can you be more descriptive and express yourself better. Stating concrete problem that you face. As it is now, your question is a bit fuzzy and hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

> I have three queue in my project. 1.verify email and number.
>   2.register user. 3.perform investment operation like. deposit, withdrawn, invest etc.

**If you mean, three separate queues for separate tasks:** Pick up item from Queue-1 once it is completed put message into Queue-2 & so on. There is no race condition here.

**If you are using same queue for three types of messages:** You need to maintain correlation-id with each of your message & use some kind of state mechanism (database) to find whether previous operation for this correlation id is completed or no.